# Locking an android device with password

Tags: android, block, device-admin

I'm developing a security application in android which will use DeviceAdmin rights. And if user tries to uninstall the app by deactivating Device Admin, an activity will be launched by ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED receiver, which will prompt user for a password. No hardware buttons like Home, Power, Volume, etc should force the activity to close, i.e. the device should be locked by that activity and can be unlocked only after entering the password.
Can u plz suggest me some way to accomplish the task???

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Ideally, this would be impossible. This is the user's device, not yours. If the user wishes to disable your device administrator, that is the user's decision, not yours. You are welcome to enact other penalties (e.g., cannot use key functionality of the rest of your app because you cannot control the security environment of that app).

Comment: I definitely knew that the word like impossible n all is going to arise, but this is not impossible. I've an app in my mobile with this type of functionality which gave me an idea of implementing this in my app

Comment: "but this is not impossible" -- I did not say that it was impossible. I said that ideally, it would be impossible. Moreover, to the extent that it *is* possible, it reflects security flaws in Android that need to be fixed.